# How do you validate </script> tag in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to validate a page at validator.w3.org in HTML5.  Everything validates except 3 script tags, below is an example of one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('text');
</script>
```

I can't see where I'm going wrong.  Below is the error I get from the w3 validator:

```
Line 212, Column 10: The text content of element script was not in the required format: Expected space, tab, newline, or slash but found < instead.
    </script>
```

Comment: Please post the complete source of the page.

Comment: ok, one second and I'll post it.

Comment: Sorry it is taking me a bit, trying to remove all of the identifiable information.

Comment: Sorry for the bother.  In removing identifiable information, I realized that I missed a </script> at the top of the document.  However the error wasn't thrown until the next </script> tag was encountered.  I guess the moral is always start at the top if you get this error.

Answer (score 7):

For HTML5, a valid script element is:

```
<script src="path/to/script.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script>
    ...code goes here...
</script>
```

That's it. If you want, you can add the `[type]` attribute, but it's not necessary:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...code goes here...
</script>
```

HTML belongs in `.html` files, CSS belongs in `.css` files, and JS belongs in `.js` files. Keeping JavaScript in an external file also allows the browser to cache the script so that it only has to load once.

---

For XHTML, the contents of the `script` element need to be properly escaped. A better alternative to HTML escaping all of your script data (writing `&lt;` is tedious) is to use a CDATA element (short for Character Data):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    ...code goes here...
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Just be careful that your code doesn't contain any instances of `]]>` as it will immediately close the `<![CDATA[ ]]>` element.

The multi-line comments are used so that JavaScript doesn't try to parse the elements as JavaScript. Single line comments could be used, but I tend to prefer multi-line comments to prevent any chance of newlines being inserted and messing everything up.

Comment: You should not escape html5 with CDATA, afaik only xhtml requires this.